# Using timer in a tableview re creates the timer after any scroll or table reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, countdown

I'm using https://github.com/mineschan/MZTimerLabel/
and in my Tableview cellForRowAtIndex using the timer like below:

```
UILabel *lblTimer=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
MZTimerLabel *UpgradeTimer = [[MZTimerLabel alloc] initWithLabel:lblTimer andTimerType:MZTimerLabelTypeTimer];
[UpgradeTimer setCountDownTime:timestamp];
[UpgradeTimer startWithEndingBlock:^(NSTimeInterval timestamp) {
lblTimer.text = @"✔";
}];
```

But after any table reloading or scrolling, the timer behaves strange and seems it re-generates multiple timers for counting in the same place.
How should I fix this while using this timer?

Appreciate any help,

Elias

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Since `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called each time a cell is displayed you should not use a timer in there.

Comment: I have an upgrade button in my tableviewCell and when user taps on the button I should replace the button with a count down timer. Also the list sometimes needs to be reloaded because the data are coming from a webservice.

Comment: If you are using custom cells, so you can add a button in cell and can hide it on click and show a timer.

Comment: I know it dude. The problem is a little more complicated than your are thinking about. Anyway, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a look at `MZTimerLabel`, and it violates MVC badly. It puts something that belongs into the model (the timer that count's down the time) into the view. That is where your problem comes from. Views should be able to be recreated without having side effects on the model.

I would recommend to ditch that class, and create your own. It's actually quite easy to achieve something like this.

1. Create a new class that saves a title and a endDate
2. Store instances of that class in the model that backs your table
3. Create **one** NSTimer that refreshes the tableView
4. Set up your cells.

That's basically all the code you need for a basic countdown in a table. Because it does not store any data in the view you can scroll as much as you like:

```
@interface Timer : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *endDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@end

@implementation Timer
@end

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *_objects;
    NSTimer *_refreshTimer;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *modelStore = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:30];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        Timer *timer = [[Timer alloc] init];
        timer.endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:i*30];
        timer.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Timer %ld seconds", (long)i*30];
        [modelStore addObject:timer];
    }
    _objects = modelStore;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_refreshTimer invalidate]; // timer should not exist, but just in case.
    _refreshTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(refreshView:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // should fire while scrolling, so we need to add the timer manually:
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_refreshTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [_refreshTimer invalidate];
    _refreshTimer = nil;
}

- (void)refreshView:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // only refresh visible cells
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Timer *timer = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = timer.title;
    NSInteger timeUntilEnd = (NSInteger)[timer.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    if (timeUntilEnd <= 0) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Finished";
    }
    else {
        NSInteger seconds = timeUntilEnd % 60;
        NSInteger minutes = (timeUntilEnd / 60) % 60;
        NSInteger hours = (timeUntilEnd / 3600);
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. My classes are so big and complicated, it takes a little time to try your solution. I'm starting using it and will accept you answer after finishing. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matthias, I was redirected to your question through my previous link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961244/set-uitableviewcell-contents-only-once. I got your timer to work and it works well. However,  the times only refresh when I scroll up and down the `UITableView`. Is there a way to get them to refresh in real time? Meaning the user can see the times go down every second. If you could help me, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the following to get my UILabel to update in real time:           
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.timeLeft.text = NSString(format: "%dh %dm %ds", Int(hours), Int(minutes), Int(seconds)) as String
            })`

But still can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: How to implement in swift 4.2 please help me to sort out this.