# Update custom tableviewcell label through NSTimer every 1 second in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, uitableview

I have a custom `TableViewCell`.
I want the timer Label in each cell to decrease every second. I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946823/nstimer-inside-custom-tableviewcell) link. The only problem is I am unable to change the Label's text. If I print it in the console, the value is coming fine. How can I reload the `TableView` after changing cell's value from custom cell class?
I am new to custom `TableView` cells so please help.
I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193087/using-timer-in-a-tableview-re-creates-the-timer-after-any-scroll-or-table-reload) link too.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

var timer = Timer()

func updateRow(){
    print("started timer")
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(CustomCell.decreaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func decreaseTimer(){
    let cell = self
    let timerVal = cell.timerLabel.text
    print("decrease "+timerVal!)
    //how to reflect this timerVal value in the cell?
}}
```

Comment: can you post some code related to tableView cell and timer so we can get idea and based on that we can help you out.

Comment: I have added the CustomCell code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign update time value to label .

```
func decreaseTimer(){
    let cell = self
    let timerVal = cell.timerLabel.text
    print("decrease "+timerVal!)
    //how to reflect this timerVal value in the cell?
    cell.timerLabel.text = timerVal 
}}
```